# How to fetch and save VARBINARY data as it is?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, varbinary

I have two tables in database, both have same column with datatype VARBINARY. I am storing an encrypted field value as VARBINARY data in the first table. How can I fetch this and store in second table?

Answer (score 0):

Like any other Field.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t10 (s1 VARBINARY(5));
> CREATE TABLE t11 (s1 VARBINARY(5));
> INSERT INTO t10 VALUES (0xF4808283);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECt * From t10;
> ```
>
> ```
> | s1   |
> | :--- |
> |  |
> ```

> ```
> Insert into t11 SeLECT * FROm t10;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from t11;
> ```
>
> ```
> | s1   |
> | :--- |
> |  |
> ```

Comment: Thanks @nbk...
But when I echo s1, it is "Resource id #someNumber". And I am not able to insert this into t11.

Comment: You have to use https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Type.BinaryType.html  to get the bytes and use them for decryption or whatever They are binary and not strings.